# sed match pattern N times

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to split a file into chunks with 2 words each.

```
$cat tmp
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7
$sed -e 's/word. word. /&\n/g' tmp
word1 word2 
word3 word4 
word5 word6 
word7
$sed -e 's/word. \{2\}/&\n/g' tmp
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7
```

I expected the last command to give same result as the one before it. What is wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sorry, seems like I figured it out just after posting.

It needs to be

```
sed -e 's/\(word. \)\{2\}/&\n/g' tmp
```

Apparently the parentheses are needed to let sed apply `{2}` condition on the entire pattern `word.` and not just preceding space.

Comment: or use `sed -E 's/(word. ){2}/&\n/g' tmp`

Comment: -e -E means full regular expression? Making possible to use advanced patterns like {x} ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way in `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/ /\x1&\x2/g; s/\([^\x1]*[\x1][^\x2]*[\x2][^\x1]*\)[\x1][^\x2]*[\x2]/\1\
/g; s/[\x1\x2]//g'
```

Comment: seems very complicated. what is `\x`?

Comment: See: http://backreference.org/2012/08/22/replace-every-nth-occurrence/

Answer (score 1):

For the general case of matching N times:

```
$ perl -ple '$N=3;s/(\S+ ){$N}\K/\n/g' tmp
word1 word2 word3 
word4 word5 word6 
word7
```